# Refresh text in Python

Tags: python, 3d-view, text-object

---

## TLDR

When I change the 'obj.data.body' of a Text object in Python, the viewport doesn't update. How to update it?

---

### Longer explanation

I have a script in which I work with a text.data.body, something like this:

```
import bpy

mast = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

obj.data.body = mast.data.body
```

The problem is that while the body changes based on my script, the viewport doesn't update.

[image: Here you can see the body is "Tex", but not in the viewport]

I noticed that the text refreshes only when I toggle Edit Mode on and off, so here there are my thoughts:

- after replacing the text.data.body, toggle on and off Edit Mode to show the changes:

  ```
  selectedObjects = bpy.context.selected_objects
      for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
          obj.select_set(False)
          if obj.type == 'FONT':
              obj.select_set(True)
              bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
              bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
              obj.select_set(False)
      for obj in selectedObjects:
          obj.select_set(True)
  ```

  but this just makes Blender crash (I think switching to Edit Mode interferes with other Blender processes)
- Use a modal operator to toggle Edit Mode on and off, but in Blender 2.80 (June 2019) I can't get them to work (Blender crashes), and anyway the toggle could be triggered while the user is doing something and Blender would crash
- Use some functions to update the entire 3D Viewport, but `bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)` is not recommended and it doesn't refresh the text, `bpy.data.scenes[0].update()` doesn't exist anymore, and I don't understand how to use 'bpy.context.area.tag_redraw()', but It probably won't work either

Do you guys have any suggestions?

(Sorry for the long post)

Comment: Please take some time to review this question.  Eg in first script `mast is obj`   In the screen shot the text object with body "Text" appears to be active object.  I'm not a fan of relying on `context.selected_objects[0]` being `context.active_object`   To set an object into edit mode recommend making it active `context.view_layer.objects.active = obj` as well as selecting it.

Comment: I used the 'context.view_layer.objects.active = obj' and again, it doesn't work. I have built an update class with the code that you can see under the picture, and it works if you run it alone, but if I change the text.data.body and then run that operator in the same script it crashes...